# Invalid memory reference (SIGSEGV) error

Tags: c++, string

I have the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    std::cout << "test\n";

    std::string test = "test";

    if (test == argv[1]) {
        std::cout << "a test";
    }


}
```

I am running the code with g++ on Rextester: `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -O2 -o a.out source_file.cpp`.

I am getting the error `Invalid memory reference (SIGSEGV)`.

Why am I getting this error?

After compilation, I am running the code with the arguments `test 0.1`.

Here is the code at Rextester: http://rextester.com/FGVB49226.

Comment: Are you passing any arguments to the program when you run it? If not then `argv[1]` is `NULL`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Or out-of-bounds.

Comment: `(argc > 1 && test == argv[1])`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, he mentions arguments are `test 0.1`.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier No, there is always a valid string pointer in `argv[0]`, and the `argv` is *always* terminated by a `NULL` pointer, so `argv[1]` is never out of bounds. `argv[argc]` is *always* `NULL`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Please click "Compiler args" at http://rextester.com/FGVB49226 to see the arguments I am passing.

Comment: I think you are passing `test 0.1` as standard input and not as program arguments.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `argc == 0` is permitted, in which case there is not a valid string pointer in `argv[0]`

Comment: @user4063326 That's the *compiler* arguments, not the arguments to the actual program.

Comment: @zch: How do I pass `test 0.1` as program arguments in `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -O2 -o a.out source_file.cpp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `test 0.1` as standard input.

I'm not sure how to do that on rextester.com

But you can achieve this at [*coliru*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com)

See [*`This`*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/442ad5a25b329f73)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Would you explain in your answer the `&&` part of `g++ -pedantic -Wall main.cpp -std=c++11 && ./a.out test 0.1` and why it's needed?

Comment: @user4063326 `&&` only runs the second command if the first one exited with status 0 (success)